# How should I call this array output?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to call this array output:

```
[{"title":["OFFER 1, INCENT, US"],"link":["http:\/\/jump.ogtrk.net\/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=1930&aff_sub=MYID"]}][{"title":["OFFER 2, Free, INCENT, US"],"link":["http:\/\/jump.ogtrk.net\/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=2081&aff_sub=MYID"]}][{"title":["OFFER 3, Free, INCENT, US, 113M"],"link":["http:\/\/jump.ogtrk.net\/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=2993&aff_sub=MYID"]}][{"title":["OFFER 4"],"link":["http:\/\/jump.ogtrk.net\/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=3293&aff_sub=MYID"]}][{"title":["OFFER 5"],"link":["http:\/\/jump.ogtrk.net\/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=3295&aff_sub=MYID"]}]
```

which is result of this code:

```
foreach($json['offers'] as $offer) {

$Myoffers = array(array("title"=> array($offer['name']), "link"=> array($offer['link'])));

echo json_encode($Myoffers);
```

I actually use this to call title and link via javascript:

```
<a target="_blank" href="'+t.link[0]+'">'+t.title[0]+"</a>
```

but nothing show up!

Answer (score 1):

```
t.title[0]
```

supposed to be

```
t[0].title[0]
```

As the data is an array of objects.

```
[{}, {}...];
```

If the structure was 
`{{}, {}...};` instead then `t.title[0]` would have worked.

```
let data = [{
  "title": ["OFFER 1, INCENT, US"],
  "link": ["http:\/\/j"]
}];

var first = data[0]; // Gives access to the first element
var allTitles = first.title; // Access to the title array
var specificTitle = allTitles[i]; // i - to access a specific value
var link = first.link[0]; // access the link for the first object
```

**Update**

I think the problem is that you are using `echo` for each iteration of the loop. Just construct a new array and push the items for each iteration. And `echo` it once you are done with the for loop.

```
// All offers 
$allOffers = array; 
//loop through the offers 
foreach($json['offers'] as $offer) { 

   //as an example we output the offer names 
   //echo $offer['link']; 
   $Myoffers = array("title"=> array($offer['name']), "link"=> array($offer['link'])); 
   $allOffers[] = $Myoffers; 
} 

// echo it after the foreach loop 

echo json_encode($allOffers);
```

Comment: data is like that:
`[{[],[]}] [{[],[]}] [{[],[]}]`

Comment: @HASH717 That is the response from the server. So you will have to modify the way you build the data at the server level before you send the response.

Comment: I can't modify it since the data it's not on my server I just wanna call it right

Comment: data output:
`[{"title":["OFFER 1, INCENT, US"],"link":["http:\/\/jump.ogtrk.net\/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=1930&aff_sub=MYID"]}][{"title":["OFFER 2, Free, INCENT, US"],"link":["http:\/\/jump.ogtrk.net\/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=2081&aff_sub=MYID"]}][{"title":["OFFER 3, Free, INCENT, US, 113M"],"link":["http:\/\/jump.ogtrk.net\/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=2993&aff_sub=MYID"]}][{"title":["OFFER 4"],"link":["http:\/\/jump.ogtrk.net\/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=3293&aff_sub=MYID"]}][{"title":["OFFER 5"],"link":["http:\/\/jump.ogtrk.net\/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=3295&aff_sub=MYID"]}]
`

Comment: How I actually call it but it doesn't work:
`<a target="_blank" href="'+t.link[0]+'">'+t.title[0]+"</a>`

Comment: @HASH717 Supposed to be `<a target="_blank" href="'+t[0].link[0]+'">'+t[0].title[0]+"</a>`

Comment: @HASH717 If you look at the end of the first item in the array, it looks like `ub=‌​MYID"]}] <==  [{"title":["‌​OFFER 2, ` The array ends after the first object ( which is the first item in the array ) . In reality it should be `ub=‌​MYID"]} , <---  -->{"title":["‌​OFFER 2, ` . It should be an array of objects.

Comment: can we chat or use team viewer please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133592/discussion-between-hash717-and-sushanth).

Answer (score 0):

your array output  is not a valid object.In the output, the array containing the object is ending with a single object and also do no have the separator ,
You need to correct the logic of output creation. the result should be like

```
[
    {
        "title": [
            "OFFER 1, INCENT, US"
        ],
        "link": [
            "http://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=1930&aff_sub=MYID"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": [
            "OFFER 2, Free, INCENT, US"
        ],
        "link": [
            "http://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=2081&aff_sub=MYID"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": [
            "OFFER 3, Free, INCENT, US, 113M"
        ],
        "link": [
            "http://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=2993&aff_sub=MYID"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": [
            "OFFER 4"
        ],
        "link": [
            "http://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=3293&aff_sub=MYID"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": [
            "OFFER 5"
        ],
        "link": [
            "http://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=3295&aff_sub=MYID"
        ]
    }
]
```

Or

```
   [
        [
            {
                "title": [
                    "OFFER 1, INCENT, US"
                ],
                "link": [
                    "http://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=1930&aff_sub=MYID"
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "title": [
                    "OFFER 2, Free, INCENT, US"
                ],
                "link": [
                    "http://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=2081&aff_sub=MYID"
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "title": [
                    "OFFER 3, Free, INCENT, US, 113M"
                ],
                "link": [
                    "http://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=2993&aff_sub=MYID"
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "title": [
                    "OFFER 4"
                ],
                "link": [
                    "http://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=3293&aff_sub=MYID"
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "title": [
                    "OFFER 5"
                ],
                "link": [
                    "http://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?aff_id=15447&offer_id=3295&aff_sub=MYID"
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
```

once the object is created correctly you can access it like.

```
console.log(resp[0].title[0]) // as per first structure
```

or

```
console.log(resp[0][0].title[0]) // as per second structure
```

Comment: How to correct the output creation, since data it's not on my server?

Comment: @HASH717 is the response coming from server as string ? if yes regex can help